# CPU/Memory Efficiency in Multi-tabbed Map/Tile Level Editor (many HashMaps/ArrayLists)

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, cpu-usage, memory-efficient

I'm developing on a machine from 2008, and unfortunately cannot upgrade at the moment. I really need to optimize performance in this tool I am building.

My entire project is fairly large, and I'm currently creating my own Map Editor for use to create Maps for my main project later on down the road. It's fairly simple, and is being designed to load, save, and edit Arrays of 'Tiles' possessed by a Map. It's basically a 2D-Map Editor, customized for my needs.

[image: Preview of the Editor]

---

When a Map is loaded into the Editor, its Tileset (one large BufferedImage), is broken down into each individual Tile (with a smaller BufferedImage), loaded into the right side of the GUI into a large bunch of JLabels with icons. I've used various Swing LayoutManagers to achieve my desired positioning.

Inside the MapCanvas area, essentially the same thing is done. Each Tile, whether empty or not, has a JLabel with an Icon, loaded onto the Grid. I've asked around before about whether using Swing components would be more efficient than using Java2D to design and draw, and the consensus was that it didn't really matter (and to be honest, Swing probably does it better than what I would write myself).

---

I believe my problem is stemming from the way that I interconnect each JLabel and their icons.

My goal was to reduce the number of duplicate Icons I have to create, which in theory should reduce memory usage and CPU usage. Tiles in the Editor are interacted with as follows:

- If no tile is selected to be 'stamped,' there will just be an alpha composite of a color painted over the JLabel's icon to denote that it is being hovered, and will revert upon a MouseExit
- If there is a tile on the active Stamp tool, that tile's image will replace the JLabel's icon -temporarily- to denote that it is being hovered, and will revert upon a MouseExit
- If there is a tile on the active Stamp tool, and a JLabel is clicked, that JLabel's icon will be set to the active Stamp tile "permanently" unless reverted
- If the option to have Grid Lines is toggled on, each JLabel's icon will be processed through the ImageFactory to have dashed lines running along the top and left edges (forms a grid, as seen in the picture)
  If the Zoom level is changed, each JLabel's preferredSize is set to accomodate, and the icon has to be resized in the ImageFactory (grid lines applied depending)

---

Upon loading a Map into the Editor, each JLabel is created, given its corresponding BufferedImage (be that empty or not), and thrown into the Map's field ArrayList. The preferredSize is set so the Layout looks right, and it is added to the MapCanvas (which is just a JPanel).

I created various ArrayList and HashMap objects, so that I could pass a JLabel as a Key, and get back a BufferedImage. That way, when hovering iver a JLabel, the MouseEvent can send the event's source back to the listener, and it can grab the correct BufferedImage based on the JLabel it receives. The image can then be processed by my ImageFactory class in one of the ways listed above.

So basically when a JLabel recieves a MouseEvent, this happens:

- MouseEvent sends source JLabel to ActionListener
- Listener uses source JLabel as Key to grab desired BufferedImage chunk
- BufferedImage chunk is then processed accordingly (which could be a color Alpha composite, a Zoom factor applied to it, or grid lines added to it, or a combination of these)

---

Is there *any* better way to do this? This doesn't take any noticeable toll on my 2 year old Laptop, but there is very noticeable lag when the Mouse interacts with the JLabels on my older Desktop machine.

Seeing as I will be actively developing on both, I want the environment to run smoothly, and if that means I have to be stricter on memory and CPU usage, then so be it.

But I can't really seem to come up with a system that is more memory efficient.

Are the ArrayLists and HashMaps the problems? Are the many image operations the problems?

I've taken advantage of JLabel's "setName(String)" method in various ways already (for example, each JLabel has a name containing its location in the single-dimension Array of JLabels, and its x-and-y coordintes on the graph, i.e. "maptile#24:1,9"), but that requires iterating through Arrays, and my hope was that specifically grabbing the BufferedImages with Keys would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Java collections are dynamic, meaning they resize as you add data. The actual model for their sizing function (used by ArrayList and presumably HashMap) is something similar to when they reach capacity they double their capacity, which consists of declaring a new block in memory and copying across all the stored data.

If you know the maximum possible size for each of your `HashMap`s and `ArrayList`s you may benefit from using the constructors that take an initial capacity. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28int%29) & [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap%28int%29) This will prevent them using more memory than necessary. And will prevent any possible delays from increasing capacity.

You may also benefit from reading the top few paragraphs of the documentation for each type as they can provide good explanations of efficient usage (e.g. `HashMap`s loadfactor).

It may also be useful for you to consider other types of List and Map (if you are not aware of the difference in their implementations), e.g `LinkedList` has far more efficient delete and insert operations than `ArrayList`, however it is much slower for random access to an index than an `ArrayList` as it must traverse each prior index to reach the desired index, whereas an `ArrayList` can directly access the desired index.

However it's hard to guess how noticeable any changes you make based on these recommendations would be.